# Pgfplots coordinates less than one cause error

Tags: pgfplots

I am generating a pgfplots graph to show percentages over time. I am using XeLaTeX to compile the document.
When any of the y coordinates are less than 1 the document fails to compile with the error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.49 ^^I\end{axis}
```

When all of the y coordinates are at least one it works.
Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}
        [ymin=0,
        tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode},
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        ymajorgrids,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
        ylabel={},
        symbolic x coords={
Aug 17,
Sep 17,
Oct 17,
Nov 17,
Dec 17,
Jan 18,
Feb 18,
Mar 18,
Apr 18,
May 18,
Jun 18,
Jul 18,},
        xtick=data,
        yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        x tick label style={rotate=35, anchor=north east},]
    \addplot [draw=blue,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}},
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        nodes near coords style={font=\Large,/pgf/number format/assume math mode}]
        coordinates{
(Aug 17,1.02)
(Sep 17,1.04)
(Oct 17,1.12)
(Nov 17,1.07)
(Dec 17,1.20)
(Jan 18,1.25)
(Feb 18,1.32)
(Mar 18,1.15)
(Apr 18,1.06)
(May 18,1.10)
(Jun 18,1.16)
(Jul 18,1.15)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Changing any of the y coordinates to a value less than one causes an error.
Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Show a *non-working*  example. Don't let us guess which value you changed to which value to get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not sufficient to assume that the numbers are in math mode, you also have to make sure that this is really the case. The pgfmanual says on page 954

> Use assume math mode=true if you know that math mode is active. In
>   that case, the final number is typeset as-is, no further checking is
>   performed.

What happened is that the node was typeset as $2\cdot10^{-2}\%$, which clearly fails if you are not in math mode.

After switching the `nodes near coords` to math modes the error disappears.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}
        [ymin=0,
        tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode},
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        ymajorgrids,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
        ylabel={},
        symbolic x coords={
Aug 17,
Sep 17,
Oct 17,
Nov 17,
Dec 17,
Jan 18,
Feb 18,
Mar 18,
Apr 18,
May 18,
Jun 18,
Jul 18,},
        xtick=data,
        yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%},
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        x tick label style={rotate=35, anchor=north east},]
    \addplot [draw=blue,
        nodes near coords={$\pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}$},
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        nodes near coords style={font=\Large,/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}
        ]
        coordinates{
(Aug 17,0.02)
(Sep 17,1.04)
(Oct 17,1.12)
(Nov 17,1.07)
(Dec 17,1.20)
(Jan 18,1.25)
(Feb 18,1.32)
(Mar 18,1.15)
(Apr 18,1.06)
(May 18,1.10)
(Jun 18,1.16)
(Jul 18,1.15)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I used the assume math mode as a cheap way to use the regular font instead of the math font